# Gnuplot: how to eliminate gap between minimum value and "floor"

Tags: range, gnuplot

I use

```
  splot "merged2.dat" using 9:10:11
```

to draw my points.

No matter what values i use for 'set zrange', there is always a huge 'gap' between the point with minimal z value and the 'floor' (i.e. the rectangle  bounded by the x and y axes), about a third of the z-axis.

Is there a way to reduce or remove this gap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `set xyplane relative <frac>` command, where:

> The form `set xyplane relative <frac>` places the xy plane below the range in Z, where the distance from the xy plane to Zmin is given as a fraction of the total range in z. The default value is 0.5.

The default value 0.5 explains the "one third" which you are experiencing. Setting it to 0.0 should remove the gap.

The xy-plane can be set to an absolute value with`set xyplane at <zlevel>`.

Comment: Thanks - that fixed it!